# Visual Studio: Cleaning up abandonent javascript functions

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I have a web application in visual studio, it has several JavaScript, jQuery files, third libraries and custom files.

I am looking for any tool which will help me remove methods are not called anywhere. This is for custom code files added by another coder.

**Current Approach**

Copy function name - search for it, and remove methods manually.

Comment: you can't know if a method i called before execution, instead your code does contain `eval` call. For example if i run `eval('myfunc' + 'tion()')`, you know it's `myfunction` that is called but by parsing it won't find. Imagine now that you call `eval(fn_name + '()')` and generate the `fn_name`.

Comment: http://eslint.org/ try this, it finds unsed vars, but do not remember if it works with functions too.